# Beginner-Question: Hey to create + open a second view? (iphone sdk)

Tags: iphone

at the moment I try myself on iphone develpment.

I read a lot of howtos and a complete book, to find myself in ObjC.

I can create my first app, hello world, get actions on buttons and so on.

Now I have my View (Created on New Project -> View Based App).
How can I create a second View and show the second view on a button click on a first view?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A good beginners tutorial about switching between 2 views: [iPhone View Switching Tutorial](http://fuelyourcoding.com/iphone-view-switching-tutorial/)